# How to pass an object from ngFor to the component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I can't really understand what is the problem I'm facing.
 I'm trying to pass object from an *ngFor to his component.
Here is a simple *ngFor that iterate an Array

```
 <div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let alarm of alarms">
    <div class="card-header">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-2">
      <span class="text-secondary font-weight-bold">
            Floor
            <span>{{ alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].floor }}</span>
      </span>         
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want to avoid this long interpolation so I want pass the current `let alarm` to the component and assign three attributes to an object and display it,

```
customMethod(alarm) {
  this.location.floor = alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].floor;
  this.location.room = alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].room;
  this.location.bed = alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].bed;
}
```

Here is what I expect:

```
<div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let alarm of alarms">
    <div class="card-header">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-2">
      <span class="text-secondary font-weight-bold">
            Floor
            <span>{{ location.floor }}</span>
      </span>         
    </div>
 </div>
```

And show the attribute's object `location` with string interpolation for each object `alarm`.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what problem are you facing? Its not quite clear what the issue is

Comment: the object alarm has nested objects so to avoid writing a looong string interpolation in the html I prefer assign some of its attribute to an object  and diplay that object. But to do so i need to pass the alarm object from html to component.
this would the the interpolation I should write in the html:
```alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels.monitoring.patient.location.floor```

Comment: @Abri Still not sure what you're attempting to do, you need to add more of your code. Have you had a look at component input and outputs https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs ?

Comment: Yes I do, but it's all about parent and child component, I need this "data flow" from template and component

Comment: @Abri Are you calling the customMethod(alarm) with the click of a card and where are you showing the location. floor, location. room and location. bed in a different component

Comment: @NidhinKumar no, i'm not calling the method with a click and i'm showing location object in the same component

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid having any logic in your template (`.html`) file so I'll advise doing the logic in your component file.

You can prepare the `alarms` array before it's sent into the template.

```js
@Component(..)
export class SomeComponent {
  private _alarms;

  @Input()
  set alarms(alarms) {
    this._alarms = alarms.map(alarm => customMethod(alarm))
  }

  get alarms() {
    return this._alarms
  }
}

function customMethod(alarm) {
  return {
    ...alarm, // <<< remove this if you just want locations
    locations: {
      floor: alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].floor,
      room: ....,
      bed: ...
  }
}
```

Then in your template

```html
<div class="card text-center" *ngFor="let alarm of alarms">
    <div class="card-header">
      ....
    </div>
    <div class="card-body p-2">
      <span class="text-secondary font-weight-bold">
            Floor
            <span>{{ alarm.location.floor }}</span>
      </span>         
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: i tried your solution and it works fine, but the object alarm still has the nested all that properties till the location object is that a way to truncate that nested object under patient?

Comment: Sorry, im not entirely sure I understand the question. Could you share what you want the final shape of the `alarm` to be

Comment: I like your way of doing that, but the custom method return the entire object alarm + locations {}, there is a way to truncate/delete ``alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0]`` and have the object ``alarm`` with a just a property ``location``? Because i would apply your solution for the other objects in alarm

Comment: ahh i see, yes updated the answer. You should remove the `...alarm` from the return of the custom method

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper method to get you the value you want to display, and then just call that from the template.

You can do anything to the object to get the value you want to display in here since it's just a funciton:

```
createMyString(alarm) {
  return alarm.sensor.sentinel.monitorings_sentinels[0].monitoring.patient.location[0].floor;
}
```

Then in your template

```
{{createMyString(alarm)}}
```

Comment: I read that using a function into the interpolation slow down the process of rendering that template, also I would need to create three distinct method for the three attributes I want to display

Comment: You would be able to just add the logic on what to return into your function, and either make the decision based on the object or the index (you can get an index variable in the template for loop and pass it down to methods)